# How do I prevent jquery function from scrolling continuously to next section?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with automatically scrolling when a user completes a portion of a purchase form. Currently when user selects an option; it scrolls them to the next portion of the form. However I'm having an issue. When it scrolls them, it doesn't seem to stop. it'll want to keep scrolling to the next section.

```
$('.tt-options-swatch').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    var nextQuestion = $(this).closest('.tt-wrapper').next();

    if (nextQuestion.length !== 0) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: nextQuestion.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

```
<div class="tt-swatches-container tt-swatches-container-js">
<div class="tt-wrapper">
<div class="tt-title-options">options 1:</div>
<ul class="tt-options-swatch options-large">
<li><a href="#" data-value="option 1">Option 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="option 2">Option 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="option 3">Option 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="option 4">Option 4</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#" data-value="option 5">Option 5</a></li></ul></div>

<div class="tt-wrapper"><div class="tt-title-options">options 2:</div>
<ul class="tt-options-swatch options-large">
<li><a href="#" data-value="option 1">Option 1</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#" data-value="option 2">Option 2/a></li></ul></div>

<div class="tt-wrapper"><div class="tt-title-options">Options 3:</div>
<ul class="tt-options-swatch options-large">
<li class="active"><a href="#" data-value="Option 1">Option 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="option 2">Option 2</a></li></ul></div></div>
```

I tried using

```
return false;
```

right at the end of "1000);" but I'm not sure that's how it's suppose to be used. Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Can you share `html` code as well?

Comment: Is `nextQuestion` an array?

Comment: Added HTML code. Honestly I wouldn't fully know to tell you if it's an array. I was using the same code on another form I had. I thought I could modify the classes and the DOMSubtreeModified instead of on change.